# Spinner always gives the same id while i select the different item and i am getting data from the server?

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-volley

I have a spinner. i am using array adapter to set data in the spinner. i am getting data from the server.i set the payment option in the spinner. but when i select the different payment option it gives the always same id (7).can anyone tell me where i am doing the mistake ?
My json responce is :-

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "StatusMessage": "Restaurent List",
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": "7",
      "RestaurantName": "Water Lemon",
      "MinimumOrder": "20.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "8",
      "RestaurantName": "Casper and Gambini",
      "MinimumOrder": "40.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "11",
      "RestaurantName": "B L E N D S",
      "MinimumOrder": "50.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "12",
      "RestaurantName": "khyber Indian Cuisine",
      "MinimumOrder": "5.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "13",
      "RestaurantName": "Khyber Indian",
      "MinimumOrder": "5.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
    {
      "ID": "14",
      "RestaurantName": "test",
      "MinimumOrder": "10.000",
      "DeliveryTime": "",
      "OpenStatus": true,
      "PaymentOptions": "VISA, MasterCard , Maestro , American Express",
      "Is New Restaurant": true,
      "Is Provide Offer": true
    },
```

The method where i am parsing the json and set the data into ArrayList(mPaymentMethodList) of string type() and set the id into ArrayList(getpaymentId).

```
 public void requestRestaurantSearchByFilter_list() {


        mProgressDialog.show();
        StringRequest restrolistrequestfilter = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, GlobalData.SEARCHBYFILTERURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                            mPaymentMethodList.clear();
                            mDataList.clear();
                            mAllList.clear();
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (jObject.getString("status").equals("1")) {


                                JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    PojoRestaurant pojoRestaurant = new PojoRestaurant();


                                    pojoRestaurant.setRestroName(jsonObject.getString("RestaurantName"));
                                    pojoRestaurant.setDeliveryTime(jsonObject.optString("DeliveryTime"));
                                    pojoRestaurant.setPaymentOption(jsonObject.getString("PaymentOptions"));
                                    pojoRestaurant.setMinimumOrder(jsonObject.getString("MinimumOrder"));


                                    if (jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl").equals("") || jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl") == "null") {


                                    } else {


                                        pojoRestaurant.setRestroImage(jsonObject.getString("ImageUrl"));

                                    }

                                    id = jsonObject.getString("ID");

                                    pojoRestaurant.setRestroId(id);

                                    getpaymentId.add(id);

                                    mPaymentMethodList.add(jsonObject.getString("PaymentOptions"));


                                    if (jsonObject.getString("OpenStatus").equals("true")) {

                                        pojoRestaurant.setOpenClose("Open");


                                    } else {
                                        pojoRestaurant.setOpenClose("Close");


                                    }

                                    mAllList.add(pojoRestaurant);
                                    mDataList.add(pojoRestaurant);

                                    Collections.sort(mDataList, RestaurantList.getCompByName());







                                }


                                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            } else {

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {


                        if (volleyError.getMessage() == null)
                            requestRestaurantSearchByFilter_list();


                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String foodid = getArguments().getString("FOODID");
                String areaid = getArguments().getString("AREAID");

                Log.e("foodid", "" + foodid);
                Log.e("areaid", "" + areaid);


                params.put("DeliveryAreaID", areaid);
                params.put("ProvideOffers", String.valueOf(false));
                params.put("NewRestaurant", String.valueOf(false));
                params.put("PaymentMethod", "0");
                params.put("OpenRestaurant", String.valueOf(false));
                params.put("FoodID", foodid);

                return params;
            }


        };

        RequestQueue restrolistqueuefilter = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        restrolistqueuefilter.add(restrolistrequestfilter);


    }
```

and It is code of the spinner where i add the arraylist(mPaymentMethodList) into the arrayadapter and get the id of the particular item :-

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> paymentadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mPaymentMethodList);

paymentadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinnerpaymentmethod.setPrompt("Payment Method");
    mSpinnerpaymentmethod.setAdapter(paymentadapter);

 mSpinnerpaymentmethod.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                mPaymentId = getpaymentId.get(position);



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                mPaymentId = "0";
            }
        });
```

The problem is mPaymentId always gives id (7)same.when i select the different payment option.can anyone tell where i doing the mistake ??

Comment: Insted of  mPaymentId = getpaymentId.get(position); Try to get it by  mPaymentId = mDataList.get(position).getRestroId();

Comment: @Vickyexpert i tried but it gives the same id.

Comment: It's not possible, but if you are really getting same ID then I would recommend you to print all ids once just before setting adapter to list view and check all ids are same or differ

Comment: @Vickyexpert Dear sir, I checked i print all the id in log before setting adapter to listview it gives the different id.but when i add the payment option in the spinner and i click on the item it gives the same id and print once only second time log is not showing anything. i hope you understand me .

Comment: show how you are filling values in mPaymentMethodList, put code here for this

Comment: Dear sir,I already updated. please check the method where i parsing the json throgh volley.check this line   mPaymentMethodList.add(jsonObject.getString("PaymentOptions"));

Comment: bro..you have added **mPaymentMethodList** to spinner but you are trying to get the **mPaymentId** of that cards list.actually if you observe there is no relation between two of arraylists.that is why it is taking every time 1st json object.you have to make the relation between **ID** and **PaymentOptions**..did you get my point?

Comment: Yeah ! your are right ! but  how i make relation between them . You understand my problem correctly. but i don't know how can i do this ? can you please explain me.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula Dear sir,can you please explain me how can i do this ? because i don't know how can i make relationship between them.

Comment: @LoveAndroid bro,there is no chances to make relation like that....you have to keep **ID's** instead of **PaymentOptions** into spinner.let's try with id first.Even though you have 4 PaymentOptions values and 6 ID's if you wana make relation..so better to pass ID's.

Comment: @brahmyadigopula ohk ! but as per my project requirement i have to show the payment option in the spinner.and when the user select the any payment option i want to get the id of that particular payment option.and when i add the id in the payment option it works fine. but i don't need this. please help me ! if any idea you have.

Comment: @LoveAndroid it's weird requirement bro.there is two chances i think better to keep another spinner with **RestaurantName** by choosing it user can get the related info.and secound one is **hashmap** use that to make the relation between "ID" and "PaymentOptions".